# Is there any ways to execute multi while loops at the same time in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

I have several functions that read and write data from shared memory and they are executing by while loop.

For example,

```
def functionA():
    while True:
         # read data from shared memory
         # manipulate data and write again to shared memory

def functionB():
    while True:
         # read data from shared memory at the same time with functionA()
         # manipulate data (different way with functionA()) and write to shared memory(also different)
```

In this circumstance, How can I execute two functions in a main function?

I tried **multiprocess** as shown below

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = Process(target=functionA)
    B = Process(target=functionB)
    A.start()
    B.start()
    A.join()
    B.join()
```

It does not work

Comment: have you used threading.Thread instead of Process

Comment: Are the two functions reading the same thing? Or are they functioning sequentailly ? As in A->B  or something like that? In python you can typically try multiprocessing and threading. But is there a purpose to doing it in parallel? And why is it not working? Its hard to help when we dont know whats wrong?

Comment: @SahilAggarwal,I had already tried to use Thread (instead of Process), It also does not work.

Comment: @JasonChia, there are three types of shared memories, fuctionA uses memA, memB and funtionB uses memA,memC. So there are same reading and they are functioning sequentailly.

Comment: @JasonChia, When I tried that code as shown above, functionA is working, but functionB is not working and made shared memory error I guess.

Comment: Can you put the error stack trace?

Comment: If youre using common memory, you might want to look at a manager. I have no idea what you mean by memA, memB, memC are they like files? or objects? there's nothing here that can point to whats happening.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), rather than stating "it does not work".

Comment: @JasonChia, I found why it did not work. I used mmap to use shared memory by objects and both threads tried to access same memory location by different mode(read&write) at the same time. I use time interval to start between two threads. Finally, it does work. Thanks

Comment: @FiddleStix, Sorry for incomplete question. I tried to give you a reproducible example, but it has no problem when I re-write simple code to use threads. I finally solved this problem and it was caused by lock between two threads access.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `threading` in a very similar way:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
```

And your lines have to change very little:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = Thread(target=functionA)
    B = Thread(target=functionB)
    A.start()
    B.start()
    A.join()
    B.join()
```

You should note however that it's not "thread-safe" to manipulate the same object in both threads at the same time without using some safer method, like a `Lock` (imported above). So your functions might have to change a little:

```
non_thread_safe_object = list() # Just an example
lock = Lock()

def functionA():
    while True:
        with lock:
            non_thread_safe_object.append('something')
        unrelated_code()

def functionB():
    while True:
        with lock:
            non_thread_safe_object.append('something else')
        other_unrelated_code()
```

Both of these can run at the same time because the `lock` makes sure only one unsafe action runs at any given time, while the other unrelated actions can happen whenever that code is encountered.

Also note that without breaking the loops (and using `while True`) both of these will run forever.